# Sticky Header Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to my header show when I scroll down. This work but in mobile version I don`t want to scroll down.

JQUERY:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 652 && !$('header').hasClass('open') ) {
    $('header').addClass('open');
    $('header').slideDown();
   } else if ( $(this).scrollTop() <= 652 ) {
    $('header').removeClass('open');
    $('header').slideUp();
  }
});
```

This is the code. I want to scroll down but not in mobile or tablet version.

I was trying to add in css in @media screen

```
header { display: none;}
```

but didn`t work

Comment: You should try media queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want something to work under certain conditions, just add a constraint.

For example, an if statement:

```
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
     /* do something */          
}
```